# How to find numbers in an array that are greater than, less than, or equal to a value?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to output the values that are less than five and the values that are greater than the average of all the values in the array . I can't figure out how to make it all work out and output the correct numbers. Can anyone help?

Here's what I have, I am almost there I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
{
   int[] numbers = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16};
   int sum = 0;
   for (int x : numbers)
       sum += x;

System.out.println("Numbers in order:"); 
   {
       for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; ++x) 
           System.out.println(numbers[x]);
   }
   System.out.println("Numbers in reverse order:");
   {
       for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; ++x) 
           System.out.println(numbers[x]);
   }

   System.out.println("The sum of all eight numbers is: " + sum);
   System.out.println("The lowest number is: " + numbers[0]);
   System.out.println("The highest number is: " + numbers[7]);
   System.out.println("The average of all eight numbers is: " + sum * 1.0 / 8);
   System.out.println("All numbers higher than the average are: ");
   {
       for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length && x > 9;)
       {numbers[x] = x + 1;}
       int x = 0;
       System.out.println(numbers[x]);
   }
   System.out.println("Numbers less than 5: ");

   {
       for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length && x > 5;)
       {numbers[x] = x + 1;}
       int x = 0;
       System.out.println(numbers[x]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that put each task in its own method. It will make your code much easier to create, read, and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a homework question so I won't give you a straight code answer but try to help anyways.

```
System.out.println("Numbers less than 5: ");
for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length && x > 5;) {
    numbers[x] = x + 1;
}
```

The counting for-loop statement generally consists of three parts (separated by ";"):

1. A variable declaration that is executed before the loop starts, usually a counting variable (in your case "int x = 0")
2. A break condition, if it's true we **exit the loop**, this is where your loop is wrong (Also your code says "x > 5" which means "x is greater than 5", contradicting your output saying "less than 5").
3. Something that happens after each iteration, usually adding 1 to the count variable defined in the first step (you're missing this in your current code)

When iterating over an array and trying to find elements that match a specific criteria (in this case "number less than 5") you should not do that in the loop condition (step 2 above), if this is true for any one number in your array the loop will stop executing. You should probably check that with an *if*-statement inside your loop.

```
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    if (/* number is less than 5 */) {
        // print number
    }
}
```

Now we have a for-loop that will go over the whole array by counting x from 0 (1st part of the for-statement, "int x = 0") until we reach the end of the array (2nd part, "x < numbers.length") in steps of 1 (3rd part, "x++". Could also be written as "x = x + 1"). In each iteration we can now check the element of the array (numbers[x]) for being less than 5 with an *if*-statement, and if it is print it.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. I didn't understand what the parts of the loop did but it makes sense the way you're explaining it. I'm taking a java class in college and the book is very difficult to understand sometimes considering I have little to know experience programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the average:

```java
int average = sum / numbers.length;
```

All numbers higher than the average:

```java
for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
   if(numbers[x] > average){
      System.out.println(numbers[x]);
   }
}
```

Number less than 5:

```java
for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
   if(numbers[x] < 5){
      System.out.println(numbers[x]);
   }
}
```

Please consider how you set your braces in the loop. Its like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I am new to programming and loops are still a little tricky for me, I didn't realize I needed the if statement. I also didn't think to initialize a separate variable for the average, it makes everything much easier to read. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't need to initialize a separate `int` for average. Even if you did, I'm not sure why you'd use an `int`, since that would mostly be truncating your averages. `System.out.println("The average of all eight numbers is: " + (sum / numbers.length);` would work. Although there's no formatting going on there.

Comment: I use int because the numbers in the array are integers and there will be no use of floats. She wants the average because of the comparison and also it is clean code to give some calculation names, for sure this is a small calculation but for the future I think it's good to begin in a small way ;)

Comment: In the OP's code they were aware of the fact that division should not involve an integer result because they used `1.0 / 8` instead of `1 / 8`. It's better to get the actual result, a float, and formatting or casting it as an integer intentionally, rather than letting the compiler truncate it.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 you can use lambda expressions to achieve the same result as in a for loop but shorter. Read more on lambda expressions here: [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int sum = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
List<Integer> result = Arrays.stream(array)
                .filter(x -> sum*1.0/array.length <= x && x < 5 )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```